# Modify FLEX ITEM ORDER when line break

Tags: html, css

Is there a way that when the line break occurs it actually drops the middle item instead of the last one? Also prevent elements a and c from doing line breaks again?

```css
    .container{
      width: 80%;
      height: 31em;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    .a{ 
      flex: 1 0 20%; 
      min-width: 150px;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    .c{ 
      flex: 1 0 20%; 
      min-width: 150px;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .b{ 
      flex: 1 0 60%; 
      min-width: 350px;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No. CSS Can't detect line breaking so you would need media queries.

Comment: Yes, i’ve notice that, so my question need to be re oriented to media queries? Hard to believe that we can’t do it in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.a` and `.c` have a `min-width` of 150px and `.b` a `min-width` of 350px `.a`, `.b` and `.c` will be on a single row as long as `.container` is at least 750px in width. As soon as this is not the case `.c` will wrap to the next row.

Good news, this is where [CSS_Container_Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) becomes handy.

Bad news (was per November 2021) we'll need to wait a little bit more to use it. ([support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40container))

This is why the snippet below only works in Chrome with the "Enable CSS Container Queries" feature flag enabled.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 31em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.a {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.c {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.b {
  flex: 1 0 60%;
  min-width: 350px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@container (max-width: 750px) {
  .b {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Cedric, great news here. So i hope it can grow soon. Meanwhile i think only way to solve this one gonna be with media queries or move to Grid System. It's a shame that so robust system than flex can't do that without hacks.

Comment: If you're willing to use Javascript, you can have a look at [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)